# Plunker Readme.md does not show in embedded preview?

Tags: plunker

I have written some markdown text in the README.md of a plunk. If I open the `Embedded View`, and click `View the project details` button on the top right, the `README.md` text does not show, just the name of the Plunk and the creator are displayed.

Also, on the `Info` panel, the markdown does not display the code syntax highlighting - it puts it in a code block, but without the highlighting

````
```javascript
"use babel";

document.onload = (e) => {
  alert('I just annoyed whoever visited this page! USING ES6!');
};
```
````

Anyone have any info or advice on this?

Comment: Can you please share a link to a plunk and its embedded view that demonstrate the issue?

Comment: Hi. Here's a link: https://embed.plnkr.co/2mIgB8pGRO7pHXpKJWxj/ If you click the 'View the Project Details' button, the README.md does not open. Basically looking for a way that a user could view the Readme in it's compiled Html form in the preview. I have some JS at the end of that readme as an example only, and when editing, the Info Panel does not highlight the code

Answer (score 1):

In order to create an embedded plunk that displays a rendered version of a Markdown (or other) file as the default view, two things need to be done:

1. `show=preview` - Tell the embed that the only pane to be shown should be the preview pane. You could also say `show=script.js,preview` to tell the embed to show the `script.js` file and the preview.
2. `preview=README.md` - Tell the embed that instead of opening the default `/` preview, to use a specific file. The filename specified does not need to be exact; `preview=readme` will also work.

For example, here is a link that demonstrates this for the plunk you provided: https://embed.plnkr.co/2mIgB8pGRO7pHXpKJWxj/?show=preview&preview=readme

These, and other supported configuration options, for the embed view are detailed [in this gitbook page](https://ggoodman.gitbooks.io/plunker/content/embed.html).

Comment: That's great. Didn't know we could preview the .md file. Thanks a mill. B